# My HTML elements embedded in Laravel PHP file aren't displayed properly when running on XAMPP Apache server

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, xampp

I've been trying to turn my HTML project into PHP one while learning Laravel. However, when embedding codes in old HTML files into my new PHP files in Laravel and running them on XAMPP Apache server, it shows only plain HTML texts without images, buttons and audio.
Here are my codes:

```
<?php
    echo('<DOCTYPE html>
        <head>
            <title>Epsilon Program</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="main-settings.css"/>
            <meta name="epsilonprogram" charset="UTF-8" lang="en">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        </head>
        <body>
        <audio autoplay id="mainaudio">
            <source src="resources/views/Assets/kifflom_music.mp3">
        </audio>
        <script>
            var audio = document.getElementById("mainaudio");
            audio.volume = 0.1;
        </script>
        <div class="container" style="height: auto;">
            <div class="upper">
                <div class="content">
                    <a href="resources/views/Pages/crisformage.blade.php" class="button1">Meet Cris Formage</a><br>
                    <a href="celebrities.html" class="button2">Celebrities</a><br>
                    <a href="worshiphouse.html" class="button3">House of Worship</a><br>
                    <a href="members.html" class="button4">Meet Members</a><br>
                    <a href="beliefs.html" class="button5">Beliefs and Practices</a><br>
                    <a href="unsavables.html" class="button6">Unsaveables</a><br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="introduction">
                <h2 class="greet" style="color: #456483"> Welcome to The Epsilon Program</h2>
                <p2 name="greet1" style="color: #779BBB"> Do you want to be shappy and free from thought, or continue dying in ignorance without knowing your true eternal self? You are controlled by lots of powerful forces you do not understand.</p2> <br>
                <br>
                <p2 name="greet2" style="color: #779BBB"> Do you want to believe? Are you everything you need and less and more? Then you are ready. </p2> <br>
                <br>
                <p2 name="greet3" style="color: #779BBB"> Do you want to be rich in powerful tools? Our time has come, so has yours, if you let in. </p2> <br>
                <br>
                <p2 name="greet4" style="color: #779BBB"> The tract is now being written. </p2> <br>
                <div class="evaluatebutton">
                    <a href="#" class="bigbutton" style="margin: auto;">EVALUATE YOUR IDENTITY</a>
                </div>
                <div class="donationbutton">
                    <a href="page1.html" class="biggerbutton" style="margin: auto;">Make a Donation</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>
    </DOCTYPE>')
?>
```

It should look like this:
[image]

instead of this:
[image]

By the way, it doesn't even change the content of page when I click the button to navigate to another page. For instance:

```
<a href="resources/views/Pages/crisformage.blade.php" class="button1">Meet Cris Formage</a><br>
```

Please help!

Comment: <a href="resources/views/Pages/crisformage.blade.php" does not make any sense.. Your resources folder is not in your public directory. I would suggest to learn laravel using a simple tutorial, so you understand the routing, controllers and views ...

Comment: You might want to read how [Views](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views) work in Laravel.

Comment: So you mean <a href="resources/views/Pages/crisformage.blade.php" doesn't work in PHP like in HTML?

Comment: It _would_ work in PHP, but you're using Laravel which is a framework built on PHP and handles things differently. The `resources` folder is outside of Laravel's `public` folder. Anything goes through that folder. The way you output things using `<?php echo('...` is also not the Laravel way to do it

Comment: Even if I don't use echo and simply write all the HTML codes in the PHP file without <?php tag, it still displays the same. I wonder why?

Comment: Why shouldn't it. A PHP page can return HTML, if no `<?php ?>` tags are involved, PHP is not involved in serving the content, just pure HTML. There's also not really a need to create your own .php files in Laravel, you use Routes that point to Controllers/Actions, those actions return a View (blade) file. The [Views](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views) page I linked has a little example right at the top (using no Controller) to output a dynamic view. Have you tried that? Have read any tutorial on Laravel and know how it works? If not I suggest you do so first

Comment: It does not display the same because your style file is not correctly included. If you want to use Laravel,  you need to understand the basics of the framework. There are many beginner tutorials available online. I would start with building a simple app with a few pages to learn the routing-controller-action-view before converting your app

Comment: Sidenote: the PHP echo will work in .blade.php files, but its not the right way to do it. also, don't wrap your entire html code in the echo, just echo the variables

Answer (score 1):

When you use laravel framework for web development, you should add your html codes in blade.php files (inside of the resources folder -> views). In here, stylesheet is not linked properly. Make sure that you have added the CSS file correctly and if the matter still remains, try this option below ->

<scriptsrc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

add above 2 links inside the  tag.

Try to refer some Youtube tutorials about laravel framework.

Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the style sheet don't get importet. You can make after your `</head>` a `<style></style>` tag and put your main-settings.css code there